# Why html from validation doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this [HTML form](https://jsfiddle.net/Thomas_nyan/ef2w1fue/8/) and try to validate at client side.
This is the validation function at HTML form.

```
function registerValidate() {
    var have_error = "No";
    var email = $('#userEmail').val();
    var pwd = $('#password').val();
    var pwdr = $('#passwordr').val();
    var email_re = /^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i;

    if (!email.match(email_re)) { 
       $('#email-error').html('Please enter a valid email');
        have_error = "Yes";
    }else{
        $('#email-error').html('');    
    } 

}
```

When I click "Create My Account", all texts filled inside the text inputs disappeared and doesn't show the error message, even it should show error message.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What's the point in validating the form when user clicks it?

Comment: @Teemu, I need to check it is valid email and valid password at client side first. Then send to server with Ajax and validate at Server again. That is the point. If I see errors at client side, I won't send to Server.

Comment: But  any click on the form will validate it. On the other hand, if user uses tab to navigate through the form, you never get clicks. Usually validation is done in submit handler of a form.

Comment: What do you mean? Can please show me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Teemu. how to implement submit handler? Isn't it here onclick="return  registerValidate()" in my source?

Comment: Now is  this validate function registerValidate() is not called and all data in text inputs are wiped out.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nnkeu0Lj/), feel free to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

When do you call this function? On form submit? Maybe you form have been submitted and all data field cleared.
Could you provide source code?

Comment: Yes I have source code in Fiddle in the original post.

Comment: Now it looks this function  registerValidate() is not called.

Comment: @batuman You've to select jQuery version and "No wrap - in <body>" to get your fiddle to work.

Comment: I use Wordpress, JQuery is built in at Wordpress.

Comment: I have JQuery wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); inside functions.php.

Comment: It doesn't work in JsFidle. Please see: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

You should return result true or false in validate method and call validate function onsubmit instead onclick